# toastr js is not showing toasts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, typescript, knockout-mvc, toastr

I am using toastr.js for notification, my drop down code is

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MakeText, Model.MakeSelect, string.Empty, new { data_bind = "optionsText: Make,value: Make", Id = "ddMake", style = "width: 200px;font-size: 20px" })%>
```

and in site typescript is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

viewModel.Make.subscribe(function (item) {       
        item && toastr.success('selected make');
});

)}
```

but problem is i can not see toasts, once i implement only

```
toastr.success('selected make')
```

its work good, Can you please tell me what is the issue in subscribe code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item` is falsy. That would mean `item && toastr.success('selected make');` gets short-circuited and `toastr.success('selected make');` is never evaluated.